# how to get the each word which has the maximum value using java program

Tags: java

My input file will be look like this

```
போதும்  1
போதும்  2
போதும்  3
போதும்  4
போதும்  5
போதும்  6
போதும்  7
போதும்  8
போதும்  9
போதும்  10
போதும்  11
போட்டால்    1
போட்டால்    2
பொன்    1
பொன்    2
பொன்    3
பொன்    4
பொன்    5
```

and my output want to be as

```
போதும்  11
போட்டால்    2
பொன்    5
```

How to select the each word with its maximum value using java program. Pls suggest me any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am no java programmer but is there a distinct in java? if there is it should work.

Comment: Is this homework? There's a "homework" tag for that purpose.

Comment: Wow, I thought the `showmetehcode` tag  had quietly died.

Answer (score 11):

Something along these lines:

- Create a `HashMap<String, Integer>`
- For each line in your input:

  - Split it into the word and number, and parse the number part (as Matthew comments below, using `Scanner` can help with this part)
  - See if there's anything in your map for that word

    - If there isn't, use `map.put(word, value)`
    - If there is, compare the current value with the new one, and replace the current value if the new one is higher
- When you've read everything in the file, your map will contain (word / maximum value) pairs. You can iterate over the map's entries to get at everything you need.

Comment: The sample just shows sorted data sets, so in this special case we could even skip the test, if the stored value is bigger then the actual one. It will always be bigger.

Comment: [Scanner.next](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29), [hasNext](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29), and [nextInt](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) are convenient for the parsing.

Comment: @Andreas_D: Yes, but I thought it better not to rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

Check this program: http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/collections/maps/ex-wordfreq.html
It could be helpful to you.